# Android Studio: How to compile armeabi file in build.gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have follow the tutorial from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i1Xv1kAeSM, source code : http://semycolon.blogspot.in/2015/03/source-code-e-commerce-app.html. I m using android studio and have problem when to compile armeabi, armeabi-v7a,x86 file.

I have try zip all file to armeabi.zip and covert to armeabi.jar but not working. I got this error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

My dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
    compile files('libs/armeabi.jar')
}
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide. I here to learn more about barcode scanner in android studio. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since gradle 0.7.+, this hack of having .so files zipped in jars isn't needed anymore, and it may lead to quite some packaging bugs.

The proper way to distribute Android libraries that require .so files is to package them as a [.aar](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format), with .so files under `jni/(armeabi-v7a, x86, ...)/`

If the library you want to use isn't available through an .aar, you should extract all its .so files to put these directly under `src/main/jniLibs/(armeabi-v7a, x86, ...)/`, inside your app project or a dependency. They'll get properly packaged into the final APK.

Comment: Still get the same error. I have include src/main/jniLibs/(armeabi-v7a, x86, ...)/    http://i.imgur.com/P2m6Kzp.png.

Comment: do you still have your armeabi.jar inside libs/ ? If so, remove it. In any case, you should be able to get a more explicit error from the Messages tab or the gradle console, to determine exactly why :app:dexDebug is failing.

Comment: Can you scroll up a bit in your screenshot to see the top of the stacktrace that explains the error ? You're including your libs twice: once through the compile filetree of libs/*.jar, and once explicitly through compile files, try removing these calls.

Answer (score 0):

There is a topic we known as: "https://gist.github.com/khernyo/4226923", But i have try this method in gradle plugin 0.4.0+, it doesn't copy the so libs to apk.
So I'm confused. But I figured out a new way to hack this before gradle support.
The way is: use jar to copy so libs. Is it amazing?right?. Let me show how-to:
If you have the following structure:
project
|---libs
      |---armeabi/xxx.so
      |---xxx.jar
      |---xxx.jar
1.We archive the armeabi folder to zip named:armeabi.zip with the folder in zip like: lib/armeabi/xxx.so
2.Rename armeabi.zip to armeabi.jar and put armeabi.jar into libs folder with the other jars.
3.And when we call

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

in our build.gradle file, it will extract the so libs to the apks.

As we know, only class files will be packed into classes.dex file and other files will be extracted to the apk as the structure in the jars.
So, That's how-to hack. Easy and amazing. Cool,right?

Comment: How about armeabi-v71 and x86 ? archive another file to zip ?